# position a div anywhere on the page but still have text wrap around it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to position a div anywhere on the page with CSS, but still have text wrap around it.

My code so far:

```css
.float {
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    float:right;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="float">Stuff that should float</div>
    Other content to wrap around<br>
    More stuff to wrap around<br>
    Even more stuff to wrap around<br>
    And even more stuff to wrap around
</div>
```

I haven't found anything that can help me position this other than in the top corners of the page, and I need to position it a set amount down the page.

A solution that relies on vanilla Javascript is okay for me.

I can't rely on creating a break in the text to put the floating element because the content inside it might change.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k1f3at98/ (the basic idea is to break up the main block into multiple smaller ones so you can let stuff float further down but still "at the top")

Comment: @ChrisG the contents of the div might change, so I can't rely on that working because the area where it's split might change.

Comment: Afaik you cannot have text flow around arbitrarily positioned elements, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use another floatting element and clear it from it, so the text can flow aside the floatting element all the way down.

example with a pseudo of 3.6em which is about 3 lines , pushing .float at the fourth line level. *`width:100%` from your own code kept in this demo*

```css
.content:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  /*height:50px; pixel might not be the best unit here */
  height: 3.6em;/* about 3 lines (3 x 1.2em) Update to your needs*/
}

.float {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* float:right:width:100% ?? */
  /* do you need/mean : */text-align:right;/* ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="float">Stuff that should float</div>
  Other content to wrap around<br> More stuff to wrap around<br> Even more stuff to wrap around<br> And even more stuff to wrap around
</div>
```

if it is not about spanning the whole width, remove `width:100%`. *(see with a pixel value)*

```css
.content {
  width: 250px;/* shrink it for the demo*/
  border: solid;
}

.content:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
}

.float {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="float">Stuff that should float</div>
  Other content to wrap around<br> More stuff to wrap around<br> Even more stuff to wrap around<br> And even more stuff to wrap around
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use fixed position to fix this.With use of below code the float red div show on the page last.See the below code :

```
.float {
position: fixed;
float: right;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
width: 100%;
display: block;
bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add line breaks. Need to update minor changes on .float class and place where you want to show float element. It will automatically wrap outside content. Please check below code or working snippet link.

```css
.float {
                float: right;
                background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
                width: 50%;
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<div>              
            Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around<span class="float">Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float</span>  | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around
        </div>
```

```
.float {
            float: right;
            background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
            width: 50%;
            display: block;
        }

<div class="content">              
        Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around | Other content to wrap around<span class="float">Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float | Stuff that should float</span>  | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around | More stuff to wrap around Even more stuff to wrap around And even more stuff to wrap around
    </div>
```

Comment: By saying that I can't rely on breaks in the text I didn't mean line breaks, I meant that I couldn't rely on the floating element being in a specific position in the text as the content might change and move the element to a new position on the page. The floating element would have to be either at the very end or beginning of the text. Sorry if the post wasn't clear enough.

Comment: ok. I am sure that you can also achieve same thing with my given code. For example, if you want to show floating element (.float class) in top or bottom in paragraph just place snippet (.float class) in top or bottom inside paragraph (div tag). Currently I have given fixed width to (.float class) which you can make in "%" and adjust as per your requirement.

Comment: I mean that I need the element to be positioned at the top or bottom of the HTML, but that it has to be positioned in a specific position (not top or bottom) on the page when it is displayed.